# How to enable/disable GoogleMaps in a Flex 3 application?

Tags: apache-flex, google-maps, mxml

I hope somebody here can help me with my doubt...
I'm developing an application using the Google Maps API with Adobe Flex Builder 3.
Wrote the "HelloWorld" code provided by the GoogleMaps Reference...

```
<maps:Map xmlns:maps="com.google.maps.*" id="map" width="100%" height="100%" url="http://localhost" key="I wrote my key here" sensor="false"/>
```

..and everything goes well but the application consist on a cartesian plane that, optionally, could have the GoogleMap displayed on the background. The point is that I don't know how to hide the map once it is loaded. I would like to load it only if I click on a checkbox
I came here after searching over the GoogleMaps Reference for some "enable/disable map" function, but I had no luck.

Please, any idea would be very welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
[Bindable]
public var show:Boolean=false;
<mx:Canvas visible={show}>

<maps:Map xmlns:maps="com.google.maps.*" id="map" width="100%" height="100%" url="http://localhost" key="I wrote my key here" sensor="false"/>

</mx:Canvas>
```

change show value to enable the map.This is temp solution for your problem

Comment: Finally it worked with that "visible" property. Thanks a lot.